# How to HTML/CSS Limit / Clip / Mask an object?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/aALJ6/ (use this, probably for the best)

```
<article>
<a href="http://www.somepage.com">
    <header>
        <div class="details">   
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>More text</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <span class="bw-wrap"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/353/324/sports/" alt="NASA Space Apps Challenge" class="bw" /></span>
    <span class="clr-wrap"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/353/324/sports/" alt="NASA Space Apps Challenge" class="clr" /></span>
</a>
</article>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
article {
    background:#d0d0d0;
    border:1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius:150px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 30px 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:9px;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    width:280px;
    height:280px
}
img {
    border-radius:140px;
    position:absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:9px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clr {
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in
}
article:hover.clr {
    opacity:1
}
.portfolio-single {
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}
article:hover {
    background:#272123;
    border:1px solid #272123
}
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65px;
    top: -20px;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;
}
article {
    background:#d0d0d0;
    border:1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius:150px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 30px 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:9px;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 0.1s ease-in;
    width:280px;
    height:280px
}
img {
    border-radius:140px;
    position:absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:9px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clr {
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in
}
article:hover.clr {
    opacity:1
}
.portfolio-single {
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}
article:hover {
    background:#272123;
    border:1px solid #272123
}
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65px;
    top: -20px;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I know this is pretty complex, but here's the issue at hand: 
This div with the details class is basically a dark rectangle, and I want it to be contained within the circle that the article/img. They have a round border, so that's what I'd want to see when the opacity goes to 100%. To show what the problem is I made the default opacity 50%, as you'll be able to see, when this div is at rest, all clipping works, however during the animation, the full rectangle is shown, and only then, which really ruins things.

Comment: Jsfiddles always work better in this kind of situation. http://jsfiddle.net/X2nLN/

Comment: Seeing the issue in Chrome, but it's working fine for me in both Firefox and Safari. The transitions aren't consistent (sometimes 0.2s & some 0.1s), but changing that has no effect. Maybe try SVGs with masks? http://collidercreative.com/how-to-create-css-image-masks-for-the-web-with-svgs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked!

HTML:

```
<img class="logo-mask" src="Text2.svg" />
```

CSS:

```
.logo-mask {
opacity:0; 
position:absolute;
-webkit-mask-image: url("TextMask2.svg");
}
```

With this, it all works nicely. Too bad that Dreamweaver doesn't seem to recognize this, and as such I get no real update of it, but browsers seem to accept it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!